# SQL Server pivot table with NULL data

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot

Would like to have three years performance report.  Sample data is below.  No date before June 2022 while report need to be all three years.  The report will be live report.  It will be 2022, 2023 and 2024 when report is generated in 2024.

Data

```
Year        Month   Amount
2022        07      2207
2022        08      2208
2022        09      2209
2022        10      2210
2022        11      2211
2022        12      2212
2023        01      2301    
2023        02      2302
```

Report

```
    2021    2022    2023    
01  Null    Null    2301
02  Null    Null    2302
03  Null    Null    Null
04  Null    Null    Null
05  Null    Null    Null
06  Null    Null    Null
07  Null    2207    Null
08  Null    2208    Null
09  Null    2209    Null
10  Null    2210    Null
11  Null    2211    Null    
12  Null    2212    Null
```

With John' solution, below is code and result.

```
create table temp
(
    [Year] CHAR(4),
    [Month] CHAR(2),
    amount money
)

insert into temp values ('2022', '07', 2207)
insert into temp values ('2022', '08', 2208)
insert into temp values ('2022', '09', 2209)
insert into temp values ('2022', '10', 2210)
insert into temp values ('2022', '11', 2211)
insert into temp values ('2022', '12', 2212)
insert into temp values ('2023', '01', 2301)
insert into temp values ('2023', '02', 2302)

Declare @SQL varchar(max) = '
Select *
 From  (
        Select Item = [Year]
              ,[Month]
              ,Amount
         From temp
         Where [Year]>=year(getdate())-2
         Union All
        Select Item = year(getdate())
              ,[Month] 
              ,Amount = null
         From ( values (''01''),(''02''),(''03''),(''04''),(''05''),(''06''),(''07''),(''08''),(''09''),(''10''),(''11''),(''12'') ) A([Month])
       ) src
 Pivot ( sum(Amount) for item in ('+ quotename(year(getdate())-2)+','+quotename(year(getdate())-1)+','+quotename(year(getdate())-0) +') ) pvt
'
Exec(@SQL)

drop table temp
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: So what is your question here? What is stopping you achieving the result(s) you want? What about your attempt(s) aren't working? What *were* those attempts?

Comment: You're not supposed to just forward your boss emails to stackoverflow. Also, your forgot to specify the billing address

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamic columns require dynamic SQL.

Note the `UNION ALL` to "*fill-in*" the missing months

Here is a working option

```
Declare @SQL varchar(max) = '
Select *
 From  (
        Select Item = year
              ,Month
              ,Amount
         From YourTable
         Where year>=year(getdate())-2
         Union All
        Select Item = year(getdate())
              ,Month 
              ,Amount = null
         From ( values (''01''),(''02''),(''03''),(''04''),(''05''),(''06''),(''07''),(''08''),(''09''),(''10''),(''11''),(''12'') ) A(Month)
       ) src
 Pivot ( sum(Amount) for item in ('+ quotename(year(getdate())-2)+','+quotename(year(getdate())-1)+','+quotename(year(getdate())-0) +') ) pvt
'
Exec(@SQL)
```

**Results**

[image]